# RDP via ssh stopped working

Tags: virtualbox, ssh, rdp, tunnel

I run a headless VM (an old WinXP) on a Ubuntu server. I haven't used it in a while, and I just started it but it won't connect via ssh tunnel.

I start the VM on the server like this:

```
client $ ssh -CYL 3389:localhost:3389 dargaud@server
server $ VBoxManage startvm "OldXP" --type headless
server $ VBoxManage list runningvms
"OldXP" {ebb9b585-84b3-4057-8fc7-e3a43735abcd}
server $ VBoxManage list -l runningvms
...
VRDE: enabled (Address 0.0.0.0, Ports 3389, MultiConn: on, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: null)
```

Then I try to start rdp:

```
client $ krdc rdp://localhost:3389
```

The above starts an grey X11 window on the remote server, with a decoration-less firefox running in it.

```
client $ rdesktop localhost
```

The above opens a [login to xrdp] remote box asking for module, username and password.

I feel like the Windows VM is not listening on RDP anymore, but the status above seems to give the right configuration, and also:

```
$ sudo lsof -n | grep :3389
xrdp       2632             xrdp    6u     IPv4              26202         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
VBoxHeadl 20918          dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
nspr-1    20918 20920    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
nspr-2    20918 20921    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
VBoxSVCWa 20918 20923    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
TimerLR   20918 20925    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
MainHGCMt 20918 20927    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
VRDP-IN   20918 20928    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
VRDP-OUT  20918 20929    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
remote    20918 20930    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
EMT-0     20918 20931    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
EMT-1     20918 20932    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
ShClipboa 20918 20933    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
DragAndDr 20918 20934    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
GuestProp 20918 20935    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
GSTPROPNT 20918 20936    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
GuestCont 20918 20937    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
Timer     20918 20938    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
PDMNsTx   20918 20939    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
ShFolders 20918 20940    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
ATA-0     20918 20941    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
ATA-1     20918 20942    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
INTNET-RE 20918 20943    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
INTNET-XM 20918 20944    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
OhciFrame 20918 20946    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
ACPI\x20P 20918 20947    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
USBDevIo- 20918 20948    dargaud   19u     IPv6           13856839         0t0        TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
```

If I kill the VM, there are no more listeners on 3389, so it's not a conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid of me, I hadn't noticed the 1st line of lsof: an xrdp server was running on the same port. `service xrdp stop` and then a restart of the virtual machine solved it.